How to refer to a Logic App standard connection from HTTP authentication input
Problem:
Currently our team is working on a solution to switch between multiple connection.json files which defers between Azure Cloud and Local Development. Since Managed Identities does not work locally while debugging and developing Workflows, we have multiple connection.json files. To change between Managed Identity and Connection String we can easily switch between serviceProviderConnections using for example ServiceBus and Blob. We also want to apply this strategy for other authentication requirements for other actions such as Authentication Input on HTTP actions. Somehow I don't get this to work.
What we have tried:
We tried to create a managedApiConnection using the connections.json, but somehow this does not work. (for service bus and blob we use: serviceProviderConnections) In the workflow itself we want to switch between Managed Identity HTTP Action Input and ActiveDirectoryOAuth HTTP Action Input like this:
For local development
"authentication": {
    "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth",
    "tenant": "common",
    "audience": "@{parameters('graph-audience')}",
    "clientId": "@appsetting('WORKFLOWAPP_AAD_CLIENTID')",
    "credentialType": "Secret",
    "secret": "@appsetting('WORKFLOWAPP_AAD_CLIENTSECRET')"
}

For Azure Cloud Env:
"authentication": {
    "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity",
    "identity": "@{parameters('logicApp_identity')}",
    "audience": "@{parameters('graph-audience')}"
}

We tried to add this as a connection type in the managedApiConnections section without success like this:
"http": {
  "displayName": "Connection",
  "serviceProvider": {
    "id": "/serviceProviders/NAME"
  },
  "parameterSetName": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth",
  "authentication": {
    "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth",
    "audience": "@{parameters('audience')}",
    "credentialType": "Secret",
    "clientId": "@appsetting('WORKFLOWAPP_AAD_CLIENTID')",
    "tenant": "@appsetting('WORKFLOWAPP_AAD_TENANTID')",
    "secret": "@appsetting('WORKFLOWAPP_AAD_CLIENTSECRET')"
  }
}

To put things in a greater perspective, this is what such an HTTP Action looks like:
"HTTP_-_GET_NAME": {
    "type": "Http",
    "inputs": {
        "uri": "@{parameters('url')}",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "HeaderName": "@{parameters('HeaderValue')}"
        },
        "authentication": {
            "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth",
            "tenant": "common",
            "audience": "@{parameters('audience')}",
            "clientId": "@appsetting('WORKFLOWAPP_AAD_CLIENTID')",
            "credentialType": "Secret",
            "secret": "@appsetting('WORKFLOWAPP_AAD_CLIENTSECRET')"
        },
        // "authentication": {
        //     "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity",
        //     "identity": "@{parameters('identity')}",
        //     "audience": "@{parameters('audience')}"
        // }
    },
    "runtimeConfiguration": {
        "contentTransfer": {
            "transferMode": "Chunked"
        }
    }
}

Summary goal:
Our goal is to keep the workflows as they are and move the authentication input to the connection file. How can we implement this for such an HTTP Input Authentication method. In the example above the commented auth type is the primary one which we use in the Azure Cloud. This solution is based on the following interesting blog posts:
Logic App Standard Connections Solution and Logic App Standard Script Deploy

what's your audience actual value here? and can you show error message in detail.

Sorry for the missing info. The audience is a client id (App Registration/Principal) which has access to, for example when we need access to API Management or the Graph API. Actually there is no error at all. I just can't find out how to make that authentication part variable using the connection.json. Both ways (ManagedServiceIdentity and ActiveDirectoryOAuth) works as expected. But we don't know if we can make that input authentication type variable.
